# {% cycle %} work around for nested for loops?

Tags: django, django-templates

I ran into an interesting "oversight" in the Django `{% cycle %}` template tag.  This has been listed as [a bug](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5908), but I'm wondering if there is a workaround for it?

```
{% for r1 in range_0_2 %}
  {% for r2 in range_0_3 %}
   {{ r1 }}-{{ r2 }}-{{ cycle 'even' 'odd' }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This yields:

```
0-0-even
0-1-odd
0-2-even
1-0-odd
1-1-even
1-2-odd
```

It should yield:

```
0-0-even
0-1-odd
0-2-even
1-0-even
1-1-odd
1-2-even
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have noticed the same problem in my templates.

You can use a workaround like the following:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}even{% else %}odd{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use "include" for inner loop content

```
{% regroup employee_bypos_list by pos as by_pos %}
{% for pos_set in by_pos %}
    <h2>«{{ pos_set.grouper.address }}»</h2>
    {% with pos_set.list as employee_list %}
        {% include 'website/employee/_staff_by_post.html' %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: FYI, putting an include within a for loop can really kill performance if you aren't careful.